# What kind of topological vector space is $\mathbb{C}^n$?

Tags: complex-analysis

$\mathbb{R}^n$ is a n-dim Hilbert space with dot product as inner product. The topology induced by the inner product is what is used in real analysis.

I was wondering as what kind of topological vector space $\mathbb{C}^n$ is regarded, especially in complex analysis? Do you consider some inner product on it and therefore it may be a Hilbert space, or do you consider some norm on it and therefore it may be a Banach space?

Thanks and regards!

Comment: Hilbert space is by definition a Banach space. So it is both.

Comment: See [Fabian's answer given here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/25157/how-to-prove-c-1-x-infty-leq-x-leq-c-2-x-infty/25163#25163) and follow the link he gives. Also, [Qiaochu's answer here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/37528/topology-on-the-general-linear-group-of-a-topological-vector-space/37552#37552) applies *mutatis mutandis*.

Comment: @Asaf: I know that. I just wonder if $\mathbb{C}^n$  is studied as a Banach space only, or further as a Hilbert space, in complex analysis. How are its norm and inner product defined?

Comment: Since you're an avid reader of Wikipedia, I really wonder what is unclear [in this article on inner products](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_product_space)?

Comment: @Theo: Thanks! I am "flattered" for being recognized as "an avid reader of Wikipedia".

Comment: Well, aren't many questions of yours (e.g. [this one](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/36710/different-versions-of-riesz-theorems)) inspired by your lecture of this great resource?

Comment: I don't think my questions are duplicate of those linked in others' comment. I not just asked about the norm on $\mathbb{C}^n$, but also inner product on it.

Comment: Tim, see also [Sylvester's law of inertia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_law_of_inertia).

Comment: @Theo: How is Sylvester's law of inertia related to this discussion?

Comment: Well, it tells you that there is essentially only one scalar product on $\mathbb{C}^n$. (I just see that the complex case isn't treated there, but it is rather straightforward).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will find the answer to your question for example in S. Krantz's review paper on several complex variables,
which you can get [from here](http://mathdl.maa.org/mathDL/22/?pa=content&sa=viewDocument&nodeId=3079).
As he explains in the first pages, the standard inner product on $\mathbb{C}^n$ is
$$\langle z,w \rangle = \sum_{k=1}^n z_k \bar{w_k},$$
and this gives the same topology as when identifying $\mathbb{C}^n$ with $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$ in the usual way.